# HTMLPurifier config error

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I'm trying to set some configurations for HTMLPurifier, and everything works on my dev machine, but on test, it fails.

with the error Class 'HTMLPurifier_config' not found.
but if I remove config, it runs no problem. 
I'm using HTMLPurifier 4.0.0

```
$config=HTMLPurifier_config::createDefault();
$config->set('AutoFormat','AutoParagraph', true);
$config->set('AutoFormat','Linkify', true);

$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
```

I am loading HTMLPurifier with HTMLPurifier.auto.php, but as I said, this is working in dev, but not testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

config needs to be capitalized.

Comment: apparently I had been working off old documentation. Along with config being 'Config', the set is now 'set('AutoFormat.AutoParagraph', true).

Comment: config was never lower-cased, but the configuration format has changed recently (the old style still works, it just emits warnings.)